# display random pictures using java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, random, captcha

I am trying to display random pictures based on Random() method's generation(just trying something like captcha). I am generating random no from an array, but dont know how to map these no's with images. Any ideas ? What I've done till now:

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Gen_Captcha {

```
static String[] myCaptchaLetters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
Gen_Captcha captcha= new Gen_Captcha();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(62);
        System.out.print((myCaptchaLetters[random]));       
    }

}
```

}

}

Note: The above code does not include the swing framework code to display image.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `List<BufferedImage>`, and use `Collections.shuffle()` to randomize the list. Using the list's iterator will visit the images randomly without duplicates.

Comment: Sounds good. But, I am assuming that will give me only the list of images, and there will be no element associated with it. just in case i want the user to input the no.s or alphabets he sees in the image, I wont be able to validate that user input. please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: In addition to accessing the list via its iterator, you can access it by index or reference. Instead of `List<BufferedImage>`, shuffle a `List<MyClass>`, with each instance of `MyClass` containing the letter and image. Use the first _n_ elements as the key.

Answer (score 1):

> but dont know how to map these no's with images

Don't map the numbers, map the letters:

```
Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<String, Image>();
images.put("a", imageA);
images.put("b", imageB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Graphics.drawString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

You can get a graphics2D object by creating a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)
Note there are also methods to change the font.
for more advanced captcha's you can then warp the image and draw random stuff on it as well using the same api's.